# Error (Xcode): Target debug_ios_bundle_flutter_assets failed: PathNotFoundException: Cannot copy file to

Tags: flutter, xcode, dart

Every time i try to run a Flutter project I'm facing this error.

Error (Xcode): Target debug_ios_bundle_flutter_assets failed: PathNotFoundException: Cannot copy file to '/Users/muhammadusamaqamar/Documents/flutter_projects/lottery_app/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/App.framework/flutter_assets/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.otf', path = '/Users/muhammadusamaqamar/Desktop/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/material_fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.otf' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.

I've tried flutter clean but it didn't help, i ran flutter doctor it shows no issue. Can someone help please.

Answer (score 0):

So I believe I had an issue with the path so I uninstalled the Flutter, cleared the path and reinstalled the Flutter, and extracted directly on my desktop. This did fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue usually comes when you add assets or fonts. You need to check correct path and count of correct white spaces while defining the assets path.

Though it is very bogus error reporting system in flutter not showing proper information or hint about how to to remove this error and lefts us wandering over internet for solution, yet what we can do when we have no proper platform for such error reporting to get solutions.